# Intercept python script completion

Tags: python-3.6

is there any way to intercept the completion of a python script, if so how can this be done? And before finishing use some kind of code? the script may end simply by closing to the cross or ctrl + c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager).

```py
class Context(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, type, value, trace):
        print("Ending")

with Context():
    print("script")
```

This will run anything in the `__exit__` function at the end of the program, even if it is terminated prematurely.

If you put something in the `__enter__` function it will run at the beginning of the script.